# Adding Virtual Keyword When Testing Legacy Code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am adding tests to some gnarly legacy code in order to have confidence enough to seriously refactor it. One of the issues is that whoever wrote the code obviously made no attempt to make the code testable (given that they never wrote a single unit test!)

A common issue is that there are currently no interfaces, just an 11-level-deep inheritance chain. I am using Rhino Mocks to isolate the class under test from its dependencies, but as I am mocking a class, not an interface, I can only stub a read-only property if it has the `virtual` keyword.

My current thinking is that I will just add the `virtual` keyword to the property. There is no plan to add any further objects into the existing dependency chain and it will allow the tests to be written.

**Are the any arguments against adding the `virtual` keyword, or is this an acceptable compromise in order to get tests in?**

Example code...

In the test class:

```
var someClassStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<SomeClass>();
someClassStub.Stub(s => s.SomeProperty).Return("Test");
```

In SomeClass:

```
public virtual string SomeProperty {
    get {
        return someDependency.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: There can be some side effects.  One example would be if any of these objects are types used in LINQ-to-SQL.  A virtual property will prevent LINQ queries from running properly because the translation cannot handle virtual properties.  We hit this same issue in our own code base.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply be able to set the property? How are you creating your mock(Partial, Dynamic, Strict)?

Comment: @RyanGates the property has a getter, no setter. I am creating a stub using `MockRepositiory.GenerateStub<ClassName>()`.

Comment: Can you add the code for the get and generating the stub to the question?

Comment: What about mocking someDependency.SomeMethod()?

Comment: You also can try to use Fakes framework from Visual Studio 2012. From VS Update 2 it is available in Premium and Ultimate SKUs. Fakes framework helps you a lot to test legacy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary argument against adding `virtual` is that it misrepresents your intentions. The `virtual` keyword signals to derived classes that you expect this property may be overridden.

I would not use `virtual`, but mock the dependency like the following:

```
var mockedDependency = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDependency>();
mockedDependency.Expect(x => x.SomeMethod())
                .Returns("whatever your test dictates");

var target = new SomeClass(mockedDependency);

mockedDependency.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Then inject that into a newly created overloaded constructor, like the following:

```
public SomeClass(IDependency dependency) : base()
{
    this.someDependency = dependency;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph. The example you used is mocking an interface, which if I could do would certainly be the solution - but I specifically mentioned in the question that I'm having to stub the class.

Comment: @SteveFenton so you can't mock your dependency either?

Comment: Not easily - in some cases the dependency is a property several leaps up the dependency chain. I think your point is the best answer to the question of why I shouldn't use virtual. I will attempt to avoid it where I can but I think I'll be forced to use the shortcut in order to be pragmatic. I don't see this code surviving in its current form once I have tests because I will start making major changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `virtual` everywhere, there a few safer methods of making your code initially testable. Personally, I'd highly recommend using the "Extract Interface" tool provided with Visual Studio and replace concrete class references with the interface where possible to do safely. Then, mock the interface instead of the concrete class.

If you're using a version of Visual Studio(or some other IDE) that doesn't support Extract Interface, all you have to do is track down all the public members of the class and add them to an interface and make your concrete class implement it.

Your first priority should be getting that initial set of tests. This way you can later make more dangerous changes with reasonable certainty that your code isn't broken.

For anyone working on making old legacy code unit testable, I'd highly recommend reading the book [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052). It is well worth the money. So much so that my manager ended up buying my office a copy to consult.